# Use UserManager as interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm using ASP.NET Core identity 
and I want to observe DIP and I create a interface

```
public interface IUserManagerService : IDisposable
{
    Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(User user, string password);
}
```

and implementation class is

```
public class UserManagerService : UserManager<User>, IUserManagerService
{
    public UserManagerService()
    : base()
    {

    }
}
```

now I don't know what parameters should pass to base class 
how can I fix that ?

Answer (score 3):

From your description, you want to create a service with the UserManager, then use it to manage users. If that is the case, you could refer the following sample code:

```
public interface IUserManagerService:IDisposable
{
     Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(User user, string password);
}

public class UserManagerService : IUserManagerService
{
    //request the UserManger service and call the relate methods.
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> usermanager;
    public UserManagerService(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        usermanager = userManager;
    }
    public async Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(User user, string password)
    {
        var identityuser = new IdentityUser { UserName = user.UserName, Email = user.Email };
        var result = await usermanager.CreateAsync(identityuser, password);

        return result;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("- IUserManagerService was disposed!");
    }
}
```

The User model:

```
public class User
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Then, registers the IUserManagerService service with the concrete type UserManagerService:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
services.AddControllersWithViews();

services.AddScoped<IUserManagerService, UserManagerService>();
```

Then, in the MVC controller, request the IUserManagerService service, and call its method to create a user:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{ 
    private readonly IUserManagerService userManagerService;
    public HomeController(IUserManagerService userManager)
    { 
        userManagerService = userManager;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {

        var newuser = new User() { UserName = "Tom", Email = "tom121@hotmail.com" };
        var password = "Password123!";
        var result = userManagerService.CreateAsync(newuser, password);
        if (result.Result.Succeeded)
        {
           //do some thing
        }
        return View();
    }
```

The result as below:

[image]

More detail information, refer [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0#overview-of-dependency-injection)